# How to receive battery level of a bluetooth headset android

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

I am trying to write a sample code to receive battery level of a bluetooth headset ( samsung made), I have see its battery level from other app, it means it does send the battery level broadcast. I have written necessary code to receive the broadcast in another question here 
[Cant receive AT Commands from Bluetooth Headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56180759/cant-receive-at-commands-from-bluetooth-headset)

But I am not able to receive any broadcast , all I want to do is receive battery level of a headset, which is already paired.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution? Right now, I'm facing the same problem.